# Asp - only localhost can access shared drive

Tags: asp-classic, permissions

I'm migrating a legacy asp application onto a windows 2003 server. It access files on the lan which is where the problem lies. The user id is a domain account id so for anonymous access i have entered the domain\iusr_machinename. This works fine when running it locally, the log file shows it running as localhost, but when i try from another machine I get a path not found error. The id i am accessing it with should has access to the directory on the lan.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's the .net environment the one accessing the files, unless you are using impersonation, the user that's connecting to the network share is the one assigned to the AppPool that's assigned to the asp.net website.

So, basically, you don't need to change the user assigned to anonymous in this instance, but the user assigned to the AppPool. Either that, or enable impersonation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28VS.71%29.aspx ).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried with the app pool but this didn't work for me. Impersonation works fine for dotnet apps but i want to get it working with the iusr account like the old server. I think this is really a permissions issue regarding the domain accounts so I am going to get the security team to look into it for me. Thanks again